# Magento 2 : Getting error message on fishpig wordpress post view page after compilation

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I'm getting following error after compilation on Fishpig Wordpress post view page, but error were removed when I remove `/var/di` directory. 
But I need this to working fine after compilation.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   FishPig\WordPress\Model\App::init() in
>   /app/code/FishPig/WordPress_ACF/Helper/Core.php(1)
>   : eval()'d code on line 21

I'm using `Magento 2.1.7` and `WordPress_ACF 1.0.0.23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed after upgrade latest version of Fishpig_Wordpress and Fishpig Wordpress_ACF.